# Copy a file to another directory, in which the file does not exist! PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to copy my file from one directory to another directory( destination in which the file does not exist)

As far as I understood copy function just works if you want to rename and the file already exists in the destination directory; what should I do if the file does not exist in the destination directory?

My attempt:

```
public function addSlidesToPath()
{
    $myAddr=$this->input->post('addr');
    $src=realpath(BASEPATH.'../uploaded_images').'/'.$myAddr[0];
    $dest="C:\\Slides";
    return copy( $src , $dest. basename($src ));
}
```

Please let me know if you need more clarification; my code works fine if a file with the same name exists in the destination but if no file with the name, it is not working!

```
ADDED Here you can see my different attempts:

1)for **copy** without basename the error is "The second argument of copy() function cannot be a directory"

2)for **copy** with basename the error is "The second argument of copy() function cannot be a directory" as well

3)for **move_uploaded_file** with basename there is no error but the result is false!

4)for **move_uploaded_file** without basename there is no error but the result is false!
```

Thanks

Comment: "not working" what error message do you get? Seems like a permissions problem.

Comment: `move_uploaded_file` moves a file (as the name does suggest) try `copy` instead.

Comment: Please see my editted question Thanks)

Comment: Am I wrong? Am I missing something?

Comment: Maybe check `$_FILES` to get `tmp` path to file and verify you're getting your paths right. There should be no permission issues at all, unless moving to directory web server doesn't have permissions for. The only issue I can see right now would your path/to/some.file is not correct. `print_r` all your vars

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure if I understood you clearly; if you mean $src I have already echo ed it and the path is right? Did you mean that? Im sorry but I didnt get $_files and tmp! Could you please explain a little more! appreciate it

Comment: However  var_dump($_FILES); is an array of 0!! Is that the problem?

Comment: Thanks guys; it was my mistake it should be "   return copy( $src , $dest.'//'.basename($src));"

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you have write permission on the directory? I don't think the existence of the destination file has any effect on your ability to write it.

The php manual says that files will be overwritten if they exist.  If they don't exist, they will be written.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php

I'm thinking this is not working and the existence of the destination file is making you think it is working when, in fact, it is not working.

Try running the script with a source file of the same name but different content to test.

Comment: I have th full permission! even I tried the destination to my document folder and still not working!

Comment: Thanks guys; it was my mistake it should be "   return copy( $src , $dest.'//'.basename($src));"